# How to store an Elixir function in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to have a database table that has an 'action' field.  I would like to store a Elixir function in the field.  Is this possible?

The function will always only take one parameter.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but I wonder if storing it as binary would work. Here's a relevant [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phoenix-talk/iA37vBFoYl4) on how to serialize an Elixir term into Ecto binary

Answer (score 4):

Here is an Ecto type I've used in the past, which is very similar to the one @AbM linked to in the comment above:

```erlang
defmodule ErlangETF do
  def type, do: :binary

  def cast(binary = << 131, _ :: binary >>) do
    try do
      {:ok, :erlang.binary_to_term(binary)}
    catch
      _ ->
        {:ok, binary}
    end
  end
  def cast(any), do: {:ok, any}

  def load(any), do: cast(any)

  def dump(any), do: {:ok, :erlang.term_to_binary(any)}
end
```

The schema definition for the model might look like this:

```erlang
defmodule Example do
  use Ecto.Model

  schema "examples" do
    field :function, ErlangETF
  end
end
```

If you wanted to further restrict the type of terms allowed (for example, only allowing functions with an arity of 1), something like this might work:

```erlang
defmodule ErlangFunctionArity1ETF do
  def type, do: :binary

  def cast(binary = << 131, _ :: binary >>) do
    try do
      case :erlang.binary_to_term(binary) do
        function when is_function(function, 1) ->
          {:ok, function}
        _ ->
          {:ok, binary}
      end
    catch
      _ ->
        {:ok, binary}
    end
  end
  def cast(any), do: {:ok, any}

  def load(any), do: cast(any)

  def dump(function) when is_function(function, 1),
    do: {:ok, :erlang.term_to_binary(function)}
  def dump(_),
    do: {:ok, nil}
end
```

There are also two formats of functions you can store in the External Term Format:

1. [`EXPORT_EXT`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html#id95506)
2. [`NEW_FUN_EXT`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html#id95128)

Here's an example of `EXPORT_EXT` and the resulting byte size:

```erlang
iex> (&Enum.sum/1) |> ErlangFunctionArity1ETF.dump |> elem(1) |> byte_size
24
```

Here's an example of `NEW_FUN_EXT` and the resulting byte size:

```erlang
iex> (fn c -> Enum.sum(c) end) |> ErlangFunctionArity1ETF.dump |> elem(1) |> byte_size
228
```

I mention the byte size difference in case storage size is an issue at all.

`EXPORT_EXT` essentially just stores 2 atoms and 1 integer (`:Enum`, `:sum`, and `1`) which is why the size of the serialized function is so small.  Anonymous functions get serialized as `NEW_FUN_EXT` which stores all of the function code along with information about its creation.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  I would have never been able figure this out on my own

Comment: @Theston.EFox, will do, haven't had time to test it yet though

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick approach to serializing a function to a string and deserializing back.

```
iex(1)> defmodule Test do
...(1)> def test(num), do: {:ok, num}
...(1)> end
{:module, Test,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 4, 224, 66, 69, 65, 77, 69, 120, 68, 99, 0, 0, 0, 147,
   131, 104, 2, 100, 0, 14, 101, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 95, 100, 111, 99, 115,
   95, 118, 49, 108, 0, 0, 0, 4, 104, 2, ...>>, {:test, 1}}
iex(2)> save = "#{Test} #{:test}"
"Elixir.Test test"
iex(3)> [mod, fun] = String.split(save, " ") |> Enum.map(&String.to_existing_atom/1)
[Test, :test]
iex(4)> apply mod, fun, [10]
{:ok, 10}
```